# How to create a code that print each letter in a separeted line

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm studying python right now but i'm not so experient on programming.
Can you guys help to understand how can i make a code that can print letter by letter using for?
my code is:

```py
def show_letters(word):
    for word in range(word,1):
        print(show_letters)
show_letters("Hello") # Should print one line per letter
```

Comment: could you show the expected output too?

Comment: Your code is not formatted correctly and includes syntax errors. I don't want to make assumptions. Please fix the code first. Your question has a simple solution. In Python Strings are iterable so you can simply do `for c in string:` to print each character individually

Comment: I suggest you go through a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or two.

Comment: What is your expectation for the result of `for word in range(word,1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You want each letter in a word to be print in a new line?? You can just iterate and print

```
for letter in word:
    print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to print it in order, the issue you're having is:

1. You're trying to use `range` on a `str` when it expects an `int`
2. You're trying to print the function, which will not print the letters
   Here are those mistakes patched

```py
def show_letters(word):
    for letter in word:
        print(letter)
show_letters("Hello")

"""
Output:
H
e
l
l
o
"""
```

It also might have looked like you were trying to do it in reverse. This can be achieved using the `reversed` method in Python:

```py
def show_letters(word):
    for letter in reversed(word):
        print(letter)
show_letters("Hello")

"""
Output:
o
l
l
e
H
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do it just by iterating over the word inside the function as follows -

#### Correct Code -

```
def show_letters(word):
    for letter in word:
        print(letter )
show_letters("Hello")
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

---

#### Error in your Code -

1. Firstly, your indentations are wrong. You need to indent properly using tabs or else you will get error when you try running your code.
2. Your code even has errors once you correct the indentations -

> ```
> def show_letters(word):
>     for word in range(word,1):
>         print(show_letters)
> ```

In the  above code, the line `for word in range(word,1):` doesn't make sense and would give error. You can't specify a string inside `range()`. You should recheck the range syntax in python docs. The `print(show_letters)` is also wrong and this all won't give you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to using Python!

My suggestion is to start with a program that does not use a function. Once you've got the idea implemented, put the code in a function if necessary. For example, in this situation I'd start with

```
for letter in "hello":
    print(letter)
```

Then you can embed that in a function like

```
def show_letters(word):
    for letter in word:
        print(letter)
show_letters("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is the answer,
you need tab separate under def and under for and under if

```
def show_letters(word):
    for letter in word:
        print(letter)
        
show_letters("Hello")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your problem. For loop is one of the powerful loop in python and can be used in different ways.

You can access elements of an iterator in 2 basic ways using for loop.

Syntax 1:

```
for element in iterator:
    print(element)
```

Syntax 2:

```
for i in range(len(iterator)):
    print(iterator[index])
```

Here iterator is any variable in python on which we can apply for loop. In simple terms you can say iterator is a variable which can have multiple variables in it like string, list, tuple data types etc.

So you can use any of the above way to solve your problem ie.

```
def show_letters(word):
    for letter in word:
        print(letter)
show_letters("Hello")
```

It will generate the desired output:

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution for the problem you have described above is a for loop.
A for loop basically iterates over each specific element in a collection/string and does something with that element.
In your case you want to print out each element. A example would be:

```
#your string
sample = "this is a sample sentence";

#iterate over each character inside of your string
for character in sample:
    #print the current character that the iteration is on
    print (character);
```

Which would give you the result:

[image]